# Usage of comes to know of

Tags: grammaticality

May I know is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> who comes to know of Mr. Lee Kuan Yew since you were very young?

Is the usage of "comes to know of" grammatically correct?

The sentence is asking someone whether he or she recognizes Mr. Lee Kuan Yew since he or she were bornt?

Comment: Is there a source, or did you write this? I doubt anyone uses "bornt", unless it is localized or slang. As for the entire phrase, it seems to be a dependent clause; we really need to know what came before it to judge "who comes to know of".

Comment: It's nowhere near "correct" - but this question is *proofreading*, with nothing to tell us which *specific* aspects of the text OP wishes to query. Personally I find the text almost completely meaningless, and I really have no idea exactly what OP is trying to say, let alone what construction is being queried.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Question edited to emphasize on the aspects, as well as, an explanation on what the sentence is about. Hope that would make sense :)

Comment: @william007: I think there must be some cultural difference here. A baby doesn't recognise *anyone* (even its own mother) "when it's born". So I still don't see how your text represents a meaningful question that could be converted into something a native speaker might actually say/ask. Since I assume you're asking about the *syntax* in general, could you not edit your question to represent a more "normal" question someone might reasonably ask?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree that it might not make sense, and I have changed it to you are or were young...since I am addressing to young and old people.

Comment: I'm afraid it still doesn't make sense to me (I don't understand what *who comes to know of* is supposed to mean here). Are you asking whether there is any person at all who knew Mr. Lee personally when they were very young - and if so, what that person's name is? It seems no-one else here can understand what you're trying to say, since the only answer after several days completely ignores the actual question as asked, and focuses instead on the incorrect past tense ***bornt*** that you've edited out anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Mr Lee. is a founding father of Singapore (should be al lot people at least in Singapore knew him), and I wish to ask this question for a group of audience in Singapore. I have altered the question again hope that it makes more sense to you :)

Comment: @william007: Please excuse my ignorance - I had no idea who Mr Lee was until I saw a news item about the funeral last night. I *still* don't understand what your question is supposed to mean, but at least now I know that most of the people you might pose it to would in fact know [of] Lee *now*. I now wonder if you're trying to say something like *"Is there anyone (Singaporean) who didn't grow up knowing all about Mr Lee?"* (as a sort of "rhetorical question", since we can assume the answer is *"No!"*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for your patience to follow me through. My objective is to get the answer as "Yes", that is to set a tone where Mr Lee is a person that every audience know since they are very young. It's like asking a question "whether you know your dad or mom since you were very young?"..According to the answer given by Brian below..seems like I should rephrase my question as "Anyone of you recognize Mr. Lee Kuan Yew since you were very young?"

Comment: @william007: I've tried to address what I *think* you're asking about (how would a native speaker pose the specific "question with an obvious answer" involved here?). If you're actually asking about exactly how to use the "compound verb" form ***to come to know***, I think I should warn you that it's a dated/stuffy construction (that you should probably just avoid completely).

Comment: The text in your question is still misleading. You are *not* "asking someone whether he or she recognizes Mr. Lee" - you're asking ***several people collectively whether any of them*** don't recognise Mr Lee, and/or whether they know of ***anyone else*** (not necessarily present) who doesn't recognise Mr Lee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I personally *didn't* recognise the name originally, clearly OP takes it for granted everyone in his (Singaporean) audience would. He wants to make an assertion along the lines of...

> 1: *We have all known of Mr Lee ever since we were children.*

...but framed as [rhetorical question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question) (effectively, *"Does anyone here disagree [with this assertion]?*, where the expected answer is an emphatic *"No!"*).

---

There are many different ways of phrasing assertion #1, and by implication many different forms of rhetorical question...

> 2: *Who among you has not grown up knowing of Mr Lee?*
>    3: *Is there anyone who hasn't known since childhood who Mr Lee is?*
>    4: *Which of us grew up unaware of Mr Lee?*
>    etc., etc.

But I have to say all those (and imho probably all variants) sound rather *bloated, florid, grandiose, highfalutin*. That's partly because rhetorical questions are commonly associated with *pompous, grandiloquent* ["**speechifying**"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/speechify), but partly because the hypothetical condition being queried (growing up without knowing about Mr Lee) represents a relatively complex past situation that simply isn't easily expressed in English, and doesn't lend itself to rephrasing into a rhetorical format.

Also see [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=who%20among%20you%20will&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwho%20among%20you%20will%3B%2Cc0) showing how format 2 above has declined over the past couple of centuries.

---

Having said all that, if we simplify the context by only asking whether there's anyone who doesn't know who Mr Lee is *now*, it's perfectly natural to say/ask...

> 5: *Who **hasn't** heard of Mr Lee?*

Note that 2-4 and all similar variants would only occur in a relatively formal context (a speech at a public meeting, for example), and would not normally include any specific stress as placed on ***hasn't*** in 5 (which is quite normal even in casual conversation between just two friends).

Also note that *to **know of*** Mr Lee may simply mean *to have **heard of*** him (but not necessarily to know anything beyond the mere fact of his existence). Whereas *to **know*** him normally means *to be personally acquainted with* him. I suspect it's partly because ***to know [of]*** has this range of meanings that a skilled orator might look for a different way of making his point...

> 6: *Mr Lee has been a [household name](http://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/household_name.html) to all of us [ever] since we were children.*

Answer (score 1):

It really is hard to tell what is wrong with that sentence. Your explanation of it does not match. You say it is asking *whether he/she recognizes*... But the question itself asks "_Who_comes to know of...?

If you are asking about "come to know of", that means to hear about, learn about, or be aware of the existence of something or somebody.  To **come to know** *someone* is to make friends with them and discover what they are like.

"recognize" means you have seen a person  at least once, and know what he looks like, so that when you see someone later, you will know whether it is he. That doesn't mean that you "know" him, but it is more than just "knowing **of** him.

Does any of this help?

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not. If you are trying to ask, "Who comes to know of Mr. Lee Kuan Yew since your were **born**?" You can simply not say "bornt" you can say "born" which I think is your intention.